# Im Encountering Issues With The Mirror Modifier

Tags: modeling

Hi I'm modelling using the mirror modifier. I have raised the vertices in the middle of my model creating a angle of the meddling side, but on the mirrored side the angle is a lot step and finish closer to the centre and not on the edge, any reason why this is happening [image]

[image: A8VdV.png]
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender Stack Exchange :). We can't see much from these images. Please upload images of side/front/top view in orthographic mode. you can also upload your blendfile here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/